# Make disk images for a PC that runs a complicated set of interacting control programs such that if a drive crashes we can swap it for the image?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image

I have stated to work with a home-built scientific research system that includes many instruments from separate vendors and four PC to control it all. In some cases two or three different vendor-supplied control software run together from [LabVIEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW) VIs. At different time different software developers were involved getting it all to work.

In a nutshell, it would be extremely difficult to recreate this and get all the settings right (including those in Windows 10 under-which everything runs) if one of the hard drives crash. (There are at least two HDs essential for operation in the "main" PC as far as I can tell.)

I want to advise them to make a disk image backup of the entire thing ASAP.

**They can worry about a data backup solution later**, but right now I'm just focused on recreating a working experimental system in the event that one or more drives related to software or OS get corrupted or fails completely/irreversibly.

**I'm imagining one or more drives per computer that look just like the ones in the computer, so that they could be locked in a desk drawer, and in the even of the emergency just swapped out for those in the computer and we have a working system again that reflects the status at the time the images were made.**

However, I'm totally unfamiliar with Windows and with making a disk image of anything other than an SD card for a Raspberry Pi OS. And that failed until I could find an exact same SD card (brand name, size, access time etc.)

How do I advise them to make these physically swappable disk images so that in the even of the emergency they can be up and running again quickly without needing to do anything other than physically replacing hard drives?

I tried searching for Windows 10 disk image but the solutions seemed to be about restoring the system, not disk-swapping. While it may be arguable that restoring is better, for this situation and these researchers, swap-and-go without needing to understand much seems the better option.

Comment: Absolutely, **make full disk images or clones of all** drives in use to save headaches later. There are many free and paid Windows tools to make disk images, such as Macrium Reflect (https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), DriveImage XML (https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm), and alternatives (https://alternativeto.net/software/driveimage-xml/). Though you could buy a separate drive for each machine in advance and make clones, which allows immediate plug-in replacement, it is more economical to use one or two large external USB HDD to store multiple images, restoring  only when needed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I see what you mean. Cloning may cost a little more (though these days magnetic hard drives are just not that expensive) but the simplicity of not having to struggle to learn about restoring (something easy for a system administrator but perhaps challenging for a lay person) has its advantages. I'll look into both options further now, *thank you!*

Comment: Full disl cloning is a good solution - just bear in mind the disks need to be unmounted (or maybe you can get away with read-only) whwn doing the copy.  If you are familiar with the Linux command line there are lots of ways of.doing this free - (gnu) ddrescue is a simple solution (but you can use anything from dd to cat)

Comment: If you have flexibility and budget, consider RAID1 - this will give protection against single disk failure.  Also, you can pull a disk at any time and - degrade the array and then build on another disk - with the pulled disk being a point in time snapshot of the disk..

Comment: If you have even more luxuary, consider running Windows in a VM.  That will give you a level of hardware abstraction and may help in event of other hardware failure.  You can then get more sophisticated and take snapahots of the VM backing devices for consistent backup/clones without stopping the VM. (but this does require some thougjt/design)

Comment: @davidgo thanks, these are all good points! My thinking is that *cloning ASAP* is the easiest way for a group with little computer savvy to change from a state of potential catastrophe to one of potential inconvenience. Then they will have time to learn about these options, round up the various people who were involved in setting this up, and then moving towards a better long term solution (e.g. RAID1) I'm hoping an answer to this question will tell us HOW to clone because "I tried searching for Windows 10 disk image but the solutions seemed to be about restoring the system, not disk-swapping"

Comment: @davidgo, if the imaging software is on Windows OS box, they **do not** need to unmount the drive! Windows has Volume Shadow Copy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service, which allows imaging of an active drive at a specific point in time, a snapshot. On my Windows PC's, Macrium Reflect and other native software work flawlessly without need to reboot.  That is one feature I wish Linux had. BTW, **verify and manually check** each image!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Interesting - I had no idea that was possible on Windows.  (Are you aware about point-in-time snapshotting on Linux - the mechanisms seem very different but with similar results - I heavily use LVS for this, but some advanced filesystems like zfs  (and I think btrfs) can do it as well.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Interesting! So we would add a new drive to the PC and choose "**Complete copy** This method makes a complete copy (called a "full copy" or 'clone') of the original volume at a given point in time. This copy is read-only." Then remove it and put it in a safe place for later (or leave it in) and at any time we can just boot and run the software from there instead?

Comment: @uhoh, Not sure why a clone would be *read-only*. If the copy of a drive is an exact clone, it should be writable - Windows, for example, requires constant writing to the drive with OS. Test on one PC before implementing on all.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik On, I've used that quote from your link simply to ask you if that's the option I should select to obtain a clone. I assumed that what it means is that while it is being produced as a clone, and after that, as long as it is left connected, it would be protected from some idiot like me from trying to use it for other purposes thereby destroying it's value as a clone. LATER, after disaster strikes, one would remove the damaged original drive and Windows would then recognize this as the one to use. At that time Windows would certainly see it as writeable. But not until that time.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'd asssume that *any time* you make a disk image, you can't simultaneously independently write to the target until the process is complete and you end the process that is doing the imaging. I think that's what the "read only" bit is referring to. When we make a disk image, we may disconnect the target immediately and put it asside. But for the Windows function in your link, one might leave the drive inside the computer, in which case it really better remain in some kind of read-only status until you need to use it.

Comment: One other option, if you don't mind removing the original drive from the PC, is to use an external hard drive cloning dock. Searching for e.g. "hard drive cloning dock" on amazon will pull up several suggestions.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I'd thought of that and still think of it. But I feel a little irrational nervousness about it - one false move... Then again, there is an IT department nearby that while its not responsible for our computers directly, there are stories of them being at least *friendly* so they may have a docking station or duplicator they can loan us and perhaps even keep an eye on us while we set it up and start it. I like this idea as it's something we can do without needing to understand much at first. Then we can think about a more long-term solution.

Comment: @uhoh Another trick that can make this even simpler is to install a removable drive bay in the PC where you'll be using this. Some of them, I think, are hot-swappable, but worst case, you shut down the PC and slide the drive bay out. You'd then need to remove the drive from the bay but that's a lot simpler than removing the drive from the PC itself. I did this for a while when I had only one PC but needed to use various versions of Windows and other software, but before a kind soul told me about VMware. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 get a storage device

Then you have options, manually move the storage device around or setup some kind of NAS or network attached storage.

For your immediate needs I suggest, Clonezilla.  You can make a bootable USB device boot the computer with the storage device attached.

Then select device to image

It should ask which device and mount that into /home/partimage for you.

Then you can clone the OS to a compressed image.

Obviously you would use the same bootable USB device to restore the image.

When the backup is complete, then repeat on each relevant PC.

Then you will have external storage with backups of all your PC.

---

Windows options like Acronis True Image also exist.

---

After that more complex/robust solutions exist.

For example,  RAID 6 allows 2 drives to fail and the system keeps running uninterrupted.  When the failed drive is replace the RAID controller will automatically rebuild the parity data with no user intervention.

The best choice here is to get a dedicated RAID controller for speed.

The you add as many drives as you need for storage plus 2 more for the RAID 6 parity data.

If you want to take this a step further many RAID controller support "hot spares" which will doing nothing until a drive fails then the RAID controller will automatically use the "hot spare".

You can have as many "hot spares" as you want/can afford.

To reduce costs, you would want to setup windows file sharing so all PC store there data on the single PC with the hardware RAID 6.

---

You can also setup a PXE (network) boot restore system that connects to your main storage and can restore just by pressing the network boot key.  In most cases its F12, but your BIOS might use some other key.

Then it boot from your PXE server, running on one of your other PC, and the backup is restored.

---

Hardware disk duplicators also exist,  for example a company named Kanguru makes external drive duplicating solutions.

Connect a source and destination drive, press a couple of buttons and wait for the cloning to be completed.

---

After that if money is no object many other layers of redundancy can be added to reduce downtime to near zero.

Comment: Okay I'll start reading up on this right away! Let me see if I understand correctly; the bootable USB device is needed because the boot disk image is compressed. If it were a straight disk image, we could just removed the crashed boot disk from the computer and put the clone in in its place and keep running our experiments without needing a USB or software, is that correct? What is the advantage of the compressed image? Is it just the lower size and cost of the storage media? *Thanks!*

Comment: The advantage of the compressed image is, it uses less space and the larger the drive you buy the more it costs.  You can also to a straight drive to drive clone in clonezilla.  The point of the bootable USB device is because setup is FAST.  Downloading clonezilla ISO and writing it to USB should be complete in about 10-15 minutes, and then your ready to backups.  Also if windows is not running in the background backups run faster.

Comment: Okay yes I see, got it. :-)